# Print if expression is not on the record

Tags: awk

I'm attempting to get my program to parse through a log file to attempt to find the word "user" and print it out to the page, or print "N/A" if it doesn't find it. This first line of code is my original example before I tried to write in the else statement:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^user/){print $i}}}' myFile
```

It works except for that now I either need the ability to put a blank line or "N/A" so that my records in my table have the appropriate values even if a specific line doesn't have a user associated with it. This was my attempt to add in an else case:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^user/){print $i} else {print "stuff"}}}' myFile
```

The problem with it is that it looks at every field and prints "N/A" when I only want it to do it once if the term "user" is not found on the record line. I thought about doing a nested loop using NR as well as NF, but I am stuck as to how that would look.

The sample input may be:

```
status-code=32 action=add user=jim
status-code=43 message=otherException
status-code=32 action=add user=paul
status-code=32 action=delete user=reggie
status-code=2 action=endFile
```

The sample output would look like (I have another piece of code that trims the "user=" bit off later):

```
user=jim
N/A
user=paul
user=reggie
N/A
```

In the above example, the records above didn't have a field for a user (They were probably status messages or error messages). Instead of just skipping over them, I want to include a blank line or some other token so that when I do a `paste myfile myfile2 > myfile3` command, the columns match up even if not every column had a user field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a flag and only print "N/A" conditional on the flag. Something like this:

```
awk '{f=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^user/){print $i;f=1}}if(!f){print "N/A"}}' myFile
```

As an aside, I prefer to avoid unnecessary curly braces:

```
awk '{f=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^user/) {print $i; f=1} if (!f) print "N/A" }' myFile
```

Testing it out using the input you've provided:

```
$ cat file
status-code=32 action=add user=jim
status-code=43 message=otherException
status-code=32 action=add user=paul
status-code=32 action=delete user=reggie
status-code=2 action=endFile
$ awk '{f=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^user/) {print $i; f=1} if (!f) print "N/A" }' file
user=jim
N/A
user=paul
user=reggie
N/A
```

---

Just for fun, here's another way you can solve your problem using GNU awk (edited pattern based on Ed's helpful comment):

```
$ awk -v FPAT='user=\\S+' '{print NF ? $NF : "N/A"}' file
user=jim
N/A
user=paul
user=reggie
N/A
```

The special variable `FPAT` is used to describe the format of a field. Here, the pattern matches "user=" followed by one or more non-space characters `\S+` (the `\` must be escaped, which is why it is `\\`). If no fields match the pattern, then `NF` is 0 (i.e. false) and "N/A" is printed. Otherwise, the last matching field is printed.

Of course, if there were potentially more than one user per record, this wouldn't work but it appears from your sample that there is only ever zero or one.

Comment: Having at most 1 user is correct, yes. I suppose I could add another case if it would help future people looking at this question if there were two cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{print (match($0,/user=[^ ]+/) ? substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) : "N/A")}' file
user=jim
N/A
user=paul
user=reggie
N/A
```

Comment: Could also do `awk '$0=match($0,/user=[^ ]+/,a)?a[0]:"N/A"'`. Posted in comment as its too similar to yours for a new answer.

Comment: That would be gawk specific though courtesy of the 3rd arg to match() and while I'm not averse to gawk-specific answers when useful, I personally dont find it useful enough in this case. I'm also not a huge fan of relying on the value of $0 to invoke the default action when you KNOW you want to print the current line.

Comment: Fair enough,everyone has their preferences.Just thought I'd post it to show a different/similar way :)

Comment: Yup, nbd either way. You might want to parenthesize the ternary expression though - some awks can interpret `x=a?b:c` as `(x=a)?b:c` instead of what you want `x=(a?b:c)`. I believe it's BSD awk that will produce a syntax error if you write `print a?b:c` instead of `print (a?b:c)`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Although in the case above it shouldn't matter as you already pointed out im using gawk specific syntax ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the [`next`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Next-Statement.html) statement if you happen to find a field that matches your *user*.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^user/){print $i; next;}} print "N/A";}' myFile
```